# Php Phalcon, как вывести список роботов пользователя?

Tags: php, phalcon

Есть таблицы пользователей и роботов. Между ними установлена связь один ко многим. В таблице роботов следующие поля id, name, type, year, users_id. При добавлении роботов в поле users_id присваивается id пользователя. Как теперь вывести всех роботов пользователя ?

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь у вас уже настроена связь в самой БД типа

```
ALTER TABLE `robots` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

А получить данные легко, все роботы пользователя с ID = 1

```
SELECT * FROM `robots` WHERE user_id = 1
```

Comment: А как это сделать через ORM Фалкона ?

Comment: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.1/reference/phql.html
$robots = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :id:",
    [
        "id" => 1,
    ]
);